# Horizontally center two divs in a row with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a div that acts as a content wrapper, which I have centered. Inside it is contained two divs that I want to appear side by side, but in the center of the screen. I can do this by setting both to `col-md-6`, thus giving a symmetrical appearance, but I only want them to be 4 cols wide.

There is also a gap between the two divs which I'd like to make smaller. Can anyone help?

```
<div class="col-sm-10" style="margin: 0 auto; float: none;">

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            Panel content
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            Panel content
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I have tried the usual `margin: 0 auto;` and `text-align: center;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use helper class from bootstrap 'center-block' and then use 'col-xx-offset' to skip grid columns at the beginning of inner divs.

```
<div class="col-sm-10 center-block">

<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Panel content
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Panel content
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

for centering the columns: use 
    `col-md-offset-2`

for making the space smaller: create a padding class and override boostrap's default padding

```
.pad-left-5{
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.pad-right-5{
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dh3sQ/